# Calculate Ageing of sold Inventory in R

Tags: r

Have a data frame with dates of transaction and units of the product, e.g.:

```
date_tr  units
1/1/2022  +50
1/2/2022  +30
1/3/2022  -10
1/4/2022  -45
1/5/2022  +25
```

where `+` denotes bought and `-` denotes sold.

I need to find the ageing of the sold products in R. There are 1000s of products and 1000s of entries. Ideally need to convert to a data frame with corresponding bought dates eg:

```
1/1/2022  10  1/3/2022 10
1/1/2022  40  1/4/2022 40
1/2/2022   5  1/4/2022 5
```

My understanding of `flifo` package is it will help in finding the products in the inventory with fifo or lifo. But I need to find the ageing of the sold products, in R. Highly appreciate any help!

Comment: In the 1st row of the input data, how do you go from 50 to 40 and 10? Why not any other positive numbers adding to 50?

Comment: What do you mean by "the ageing of the sold products"?

Comment: Ageing is the time difference between buy and sell.

Comment: How did you get these values of 10 and 40 in the bottom table as your output? Struggling to understand the computation. You might have to @ our username for us to get notified.

Comment: @dcsuka The output is just mapping of the sold inventory to the purchase dates. the 10 units sold on 1/3/2022 were bought on 1/1/2022. The 45 units sold on 1/4/2022, a part of that were bought on 1/1/2022 and a part were bought on 1/2/2022.

Comment: But how do you get exactly 10, 40, and 5? This goes back to Rui Barradas' question. Why not 20, 30, and 30? If we only have the input, for example, the ten sold on Jan 3 could have been bought on either of the two days beforehand, we do not know.

Comment: @dcsuka Because fifo order for sales

Comment: Can you walk me through how exactly that calculation works, and all the sample data you start with?

Comment: Still unclear how you calculate the numbers. What do you mean fifo order for the sales? Is the implemented in the first dataframe?